How to form groups based on the length of a column and total of another?
My input is this dataframe :
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J'],
 'VAL': [9, 5, 8, 2, 6, 1, 1, 1, 2, 11]})

print(df)

  ID  VAL
0  A    9
1  B    5
2  C    8
3  D    2
4  E    6
5  F    1
6  G    1
7  H    1
8  I    2
9  J   11

I'm trying to create a flag column GROUP that is based on this logic: we should pick at most three rows of column ID and at the same time keep an eye on column VAL and make sure it doesn't exceed 10 and if true, the tracker should stop picking and move to the next group.
The expected output is this :
  ID  VAL  GROUP
0  A    9      1
1  B    5      2
2  C    8      3
3  D    2      3
4  E    6      4
5  F    1      4
6  G    1      4
7  H    1      5
8  I    2      5
9  J   11      6

I tried implementing the logic but the group numbers are more than expected :
identifier1 = df['VAL'].cumsum() // 10
identifier2 = [i // 3 for i in range(len(df))]

df['GROUP'] = df.groupby([identifier1, identifier2]).ngroup() + 1

print(df)

  ID  VAL  GROUP
0  A    9      1
1  B    5      2
2  C    8      3
3  D    2      4
4  E    6      5
5  F    1      5
6  G    1      6
7  H    1      6
8  I    2      6
9  J   11      7

Do you guys know how to fix this ?

You can't vectorize this operation, you need to loop and can optionally optimize the speed using numba:
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def group(s, maximum=10, n=3):
    total = 0
    count = 0
    g = 1
    groups = []
    for v in s:
        total += v
        count +=1
        if total > maximum or count >= n:
            g += 1
            total = v
            count = 0
        groups.append(g)
    return groups

df['GROUP'] = group(df['VAL'].to_numpy())

Output:
  ID  VAL  GROUP
0  A    9      1
1  B    5      2
2  C    8      3
3  D    2      3
4  E    6      4
5  F    1      4
6  G    1      4
7  H    1      5
8  I    2      5
9  J   11      6


You're awesome, thank you. If you can show me how to return a list of dataframes without the new column, I will be grateful.

You can split the DataFrame with out = [g for _, g in df.groupby(group(df['VAL'].to_numpy()))].

Try this:
s = df['VAL'].cumsum().floordiv(10).add(1)

s.add((df.groupby(s).cumcount().mod(3).eq(0) & df.groupby(s).cumcount().ne(0)).cumsum())

Output:
0    1
1    2
2    3
3    3
4    4
5    4
6    4
7    5
8    5
9    6

